# Setting Maven for scripting languages?

Tags: maven, tcl, pom.xml, jacl

Maven is for building and managing any Java-based project. But what happens if a project is in a scripting language?

All maven can do now with TCL is copy the files around and put them in the right place in the target directory.

My problems are as follows:

1. Code is in TCL-> need of an interpreter not of a compiler.
2. It doesn't see any Java code, so it doesn't compile anything.
3. It doesn't see any Java tests, so it doesn't run them.
4. There's no java to run coverage against, so the jococo won't have anything to do.

Is there any way to set up maven for supporting a TCL project?

I've searched a lot in the internet and I found only 'jacl', but I don't really know how I can use it for setting up Maven.

Comment: Perhaps you could find some answers from [this repo](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/dltk/org.eclipse.dltk.tcl/+/master/tcl/tests/), as it seems to have TCL tests in a maven project?

Comment: That's interesting! But I don't see any code in TCL, just in Java. Correct me if I see it wrong.

Comment: Stuff under `[...]core.tests/rawtests` in the folder structure appears to be TCL though. So even though it's the source code for Dynamic Languages Toolkit for Eclipse, might be something there. However, I don't know anything about TCL, so don't take my word for it. Just jumped at me, when I did a quick Google search for this topic and figured I'd mention it, as you said you didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl isn't closely integrated with Maven (unlike Java) so you'll have to do more work. To run a Tcl script from Maven, the simplest way is to use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), but you *have* to bind the executions to  explicit lifecycle phases yourself instead of relying on defaults. For example, to run a script during the `test` phase (i.e., to do `tclsh testscript.tcl anotherArgument`), you use:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-tcl-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>tclsh</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>testscript.tcl</argument>
                            <argument>anotherArgument</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Maven's long-winded! Don't forget that you can probably put much of the complexity in a parent POM, and you can use properties and profiles to do interesting things.

You can also use the `java` goal to run Jacl or jTcl interpreters (in a sub-process). It depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: You could also make a Maven plugin to run Tcl, but that's _way_ more work. (If you do, please make it available to others and do an announcement on comp.lang.tcl…)

Comment: Thanks, Donal! I'll try your solution. If I get it correctly, that could work only for one file? or I could set as an argument *.tcl meaning that it can run all the .tcl files?

Comment: Tcl doesn't do that by default. You'd need a library script that takes in all the filenames as arguments and runs each of them. Crudely, with no error handling: `foreach filename $argv {source $filename}` or perhaps `foreach filename $argv {puts [exec [info nameofexecutable] $filename]}` but I reckon you will need to tweak beyond those recipes. You might be better off asking a separate question on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using [jTcl](https://kenai.com/nonav/projects/jtcl/) I don't see what Maven will do, apart from complicate your build process. Unless you understand Maven well and can develop some supporting plugins. As you've pointed out TCL is a scripting language, meaning your real challenge is a run-time **deployment** problem.

So, how would a TCL build process make deployment simpler? I would propose building RPM, Debian or MSI package for each targeted environment. These native installers can use dependency management to ensure the TCL interprertor is also installed. Another useful build option are [starkits](http://equi4.com/starkit/), which would bundle the TCL interpretor in a single file.

Once built, these binaries can be stored in your Maven repository (like jar files) and used as part of your deployment process. And finally don't forget you are not forced to use Maven as your build tool.

**Disclaimer:** Been a while since I've programmed with TCL, so hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But actually...I am forced to use Maven, indeed! This is a project on my work and I just try to setup everything locally, which is clearly a pain.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much "not the maven way" to make dependencies on external build tools outside the maven ecosystem.  Linking to tclsh will break your builds if tclsh isn't available.  Not saying I haven't done worse (sometimes you just have to get it done and forget "the maven way").  Fortunately, there is an alternative - [jacl](http://tcljava.sourceforge.net/docs/website/index.html).

First download the latest (probably 1.4.1) prebuilt jacl binary zip file from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcljava/files/jacl/).

Next, unzip and go into the lib/tcljava1.4.1 subdirectory.  There are four jar files here you need to publish to your local repository (or another repo you use):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tjc.jar -DgroupId=jacl -DartifactId=tjc -Dversion=1.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tcljava.jar -DgroupId=jacl -DartifactId=tcljava -Dversion=1.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jacl.jar -DgroupId=jacl -DartifactId=jacl -Dversion=1.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=itcl.jar -DgroupId=jacl -DartifactId=itcl -Dversion=1.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You'll also need to add these as dependencies to the project where you're calling the tcl script:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jacl</groupId>
    <artifactId>itcl</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jacl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacl</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jacl</groupId>
    <artifactId>tcljava</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jacl</groupId>
    <artifactId>tjc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then just call the tcl (or really jacl) script using the **exec** goal of the exec-maven-plugin, passing in the script file path as the first argument (customize the execution as necessary to bind to the proper phase, etc.):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>runTcl</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-Dbasedir=${basedir}</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>tcl.lang.Shell</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/scripts/myScript.tcl</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Update: Note that I had to use the "exec" goal above instead of the java goal.  That's because jacl calls System.exit() in it's main function, so it kills the jvm.  With this config, you can fail the build by using:

```
package require java
java::call System exit 1
```

From within your tcl code (or any exit value other than zero or other successCodes configured in the plugin). Hope that helps.