# Run bash script before build started

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent pom file which declares some modules, like

```
<modules>
    <module>execution</module>
    <module>model</module>
</modules>
```

The thing is there is a bash script `bootstrap.sh` on the same level as the parent `pom.xml` which I want to execute before the builiding of the modules listed above is started.

Is it possible to do so with maven? Or there is another way to have the `bootstrap.sh` executed before the compilation of the modules begins.

Comment: Depends on how you run your build, there's always writing another shell script to glue the two together

Comment: I would ask the question. What is the purpose of that script?

Comment: this may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433652/is-it-possible-to-run-a-bash-script-from-maven

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to compile a project written in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building multi module projects, aggregator will be built first, and modules will be built in an order based on the dependencies between them.

You can add the following plugin to your aggregator(it's the parent pom you mentioned in the question) pom.xml to solve your problem. I choose initialize for this to be executed, but You could have choose install also. Check out [lifecycle.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) Imported thing here this code will be executed when a maven command that is later in the lifecycle is issued. (Ex: If You choose install as the phase, and execute mvn package this wont be executed.)

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>Run Script</id>
          <phase>initialize</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <executable>bootstrap.sh</executable>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```