# How we can add test that is written using shell script inside our maven project?

Tags: java, shell, pom.xml

How we can add test that is written using shell script inside our maven project? is there is template that will use maven-ant-run plugin ?

Is there is generalied way to doing that i need to perform this test before building tarball.

Comment: General answer: there are plugins for that, e.g. the [`bash-maven-plugin` (`bitbucket.org`)](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bash-maven-plugin/src/master/). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433652/is-it-possible-to-run-a-bash-script-from-maven) seems very similar. --- I would regard this as somewhat of a smell. Why do the tests need a bash script?