# Pre-populate MongoDB database with Maven

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

I want to pre-populate MongoDB database in Maven Java project with some data for integration testing purposes. I can easily achieve this by executing script in mongo shell manually (`./mongo server:port/database --quiet my_script.js`), but how can I do this using Maven?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how about portability? If one of our developers uses Windows (and can't execute shell script) what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Mongo Java API](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial) to run your script into the database with the [`DB.doEval()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#doEval%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method. If you already have a running database then connecting and running the script could be done as part of your test setup.

That said, for some of my projects, I am using Maven with [embedmongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/embedmongo.flapdoodle.de) Maven plugin, which allows a mongo database to be created on the fly for integration testing. That, combined with your script might be an alternate solution that does not rely on an existing Mongo database to be running.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be the right solution. And (if it matters) I use Spring Data for MongoDB in my project, but I can easily access underlying API.

Answer (score 4):

Is the MongoDB database running before the tests are run? Or do you start the server as part of your tests?

In either case, I think it would be possible to use dbunit maven plugin to load an external file with testdata. Take a look at http://mojo.codehaus.org/dbunit-maven-plugin/operation-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think that DBUnit is able to work with MongoDB database.

Comment: Ok, I figured it had a standard jdbc driver. Maybe NoSQLUnit might be something then: http://www.lordofthejars.com/2012/06/nosqlunit-030-released.html

Comment: Thank you! It looks like NoSQLUnit is under active development and I definitely give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [embedmongo-maven-plugin](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/embedmongo-maven-plugin) to achieve this. It has a `mongoimport` goal to run mongoimport or a `mongo-scripts` goal to eval arbitrary js scripts.