# How can I copy an entire directory into another directory using Maven?

Tags: maven

I want to know how to copy an entire directory into another directory using Maven without using the Mmaven antrun plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html).

As an example taken from their documentation:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

This would copy the content of the `directory` into the `outputDirectory` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `<phase>validate</phase>` did it for me, thank you! Now Maven runs copy-resources whenever I save any file in my project :)

Comment: Yes, but you're basically recreating the input directory as the output directory instead of "copy an entire directory into another directory". If I wanted to include another resource, it would need a whole other execution with its own outputDirectory

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.2</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>copy</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
               <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
               </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is correct.**

However, there are some caveats in terms of the life-cycle phase the resource plugin is configured to as well as other downstream plugins, e.g. WAR plugin and in an auto-build environment due to the above, files don't get copied in the required folders many times and it is difficult to debug without very extensive knowledge of the upstream and downstream plugins.

In that context, since resource is a built in plug-in and binds to certain life-cycle phases in different project types, it is better to avoid using and overriding it's behaviour if possible.

It is better to use exec-maven-plugin to copy external files.

Refer: [I want to execute shell commands from Maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)

An example is given below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>copy-svn-export</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>cp</executable>
        <commandlineArgs>-r ./src_svn_export/. ./src/</commandlineArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```