# run calabash-android tests during Maven build

Tags: maven, calabash

First off, I suspect this isn't going to be easy, because there isn't an entry for calabash-android in the Maven central repository and the calabash-android project doesn't provide one.

That being said, does anyone know how to manage calabash-android tests during a Maven build? Are there any plugins for this? I can't find any, but in the off chance my google-fu has failed me or there's a workaround... I'd love to hear about it.

[edit] I'm using the maven-android plugin for the apk build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are familiar with the [Android Maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)? If not, you should check it out. Here is a method that is not bulletproof, but should work:

1- Start by writing a shell script that launches the Calabash tests. This shell script, say `calabash.sh`, wouldn't be too complicated, just something along the lines of:

```
calabash-android run ../target/<app>.apk /path/to/calabash/tests
```

2- Launch this script once `maven` has finished its `integration-test` phase (if you are using `Android Maven`, that's when you run your unit tests). This is taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Version Calculation</id>
      <phase>validate</phase> //This occurs [after integration-test][3]
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>${basedir}/scripts/calabash.sh</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is not a bulletproof solution because I suspect that Maven cannot report any calabash test failures. Also, you might need to add some bash magic to make the script run until completion before Maven finishes building.

Comment: Thanks verybadalloc. That does seem like the most idiomatic way to handle this, too bad about reports.

Comment: calabash-android is open sourced.  you might consider make a pull request with this feature.

Comment: @jmoody would love to, but this feature will require making changes to maven, and not calabash.