# executing shell script and ant script with named parameter using maven

Tags: maven, ant

I am implementing maven wrapper to ant builds. And the ant command used to build the project is as follows

```
ant -v -f build.xml -Darch=linux-java7 -Dconfig=/work/build.config -Doutput=/work/bldout/
```

Now i have to execute the above command through maven . I tried to implement this using "[I want to execute shell commands from maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)" and "http://sanchitbahal.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/maven-exec-plugin-vs-maven-antrun-plugin-for-running-command-line-tool/"

The sample code i tried inside my pom.xml is as follows :

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <executions>
             <execution>
             <id>execute-shell</id>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                      <executable>test.sh</executable>
                      <arguments>
                            <argument>ARG1</argument>
                            <argument>ARG2</argument>
                      </arguments>
             </configuration>
             </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

But i am not able to figure out how to pass named parameter such as "-Darch=linux-java7" as arguement to build.xml

Also used maven-antrun plugin to invoke build.xml as follows :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>

     <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>run-target</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
              <configuration>
                 <target>
                    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="all" />
                 </target>
              </configuration>
          <goals>
             <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
```

But here also i am unable to figure out how to pass parameter such as "-Darch=linux-java7" as arguement to build.xml

What i know is that i can put the command in a shell script(in a .sh file) and call the shell script using maven-exec-plugin , but wanted to know if it is possible to do without doing so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use antrun, it has less external dependencies (like ant executable on path etc.)

Ant tasks executed by antrun plugin inherit all properties defined inside the `properties` section of your pom.

So you simple need to include:

```
<properties>
  <arch>linux-java7</arch>
  ...
</properties>
```

inside your pom to make it work.

Comment: ok , will try adding them in properties tag , also do you know how can i pass -v and -f ant options through pom ? Are those options really necessary when ant is executed through antrun plugin?

Comment: `-f build.xml` is uncessary even while calling from the command line, since the default is `build.xml`. `-v` gives verbose output. There is IMHO no readily available option to do that with antrun (except turning verbose on for the whole maven job using `-X`, do you really need `verbose` output? The idea of verbose is to log extra (debug) information in case something goes wrong, this should not be the default.

Comment: ok , have to speak about it with my teammates , this is the first time i am using ant , better i have to go through ant first . Thanks