# Update database record after maven build

Tags: sql, maven, build, package, firebird

I wonder if there is any way to update Firebird's database record after (or during) maven's build. This is necessary to refresh application's version in db. Is there any maven plugin or possibility to run any shell script after package maven's goal? Thank for any support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to execute shell commands from maven's pom.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)

Comment: This sounds more like a job for CI solution like Jenkins to do this after a successful release build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any shell command from maven using the [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

Here's an example configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>obfuscate</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-jar</argument>

        <!-- Change the value to your  jar -->
        <argument>path/to/your/Programm.jar</argument>

        <!-- Jar-Args -->
        <argument>arg1</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```