# In Java Maven project, how does resource folder and target folder map?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java Maven project. I have some script A stored under `src/main/resources` folder.

I found that after `mvn` install, everything under resource folder will be copied to target folder. So here comes my question:

Let's say my script A (a Windows `.bat` file), when run, will access file B, which is also under `src/main/resources`, and generate result file `C`, which I intend to put also under `src/main/resources`.

And my script A looks like this:

```
some command  `c:\project\...\src\main\resource\B`
```

How will Maven run?

will it

1. run everything (A, B, create C) under `src/main/resources`, and copy the result to target folder? or
2. will it copy A, B to target folder and run from there?

If it is 2), should I change my script A to change path of B to target folder?

Comment: Are you running the script as part of the maven build?  If so, how are you doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven, or the maven-resources-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) will not run your script at all. Its task is to copy resources to the target of your project.

You could utilize the exec-maven-plugin to do this as described [here] ([I want to execute shell commands from maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)). Note that you should be very careful with system specific assumptions about path and OS specific scripts within you build process.