# Execute some shell code before Maven package

Tags: maven

When I package a jar, the jar will include some files from the other directory. I want `maven package` to automatically to run a shell script to check if the dependency directory is clean and up-to-date. If the script returns non-zero, then `maven packet` should stop. Is that possible? If yes, how to implement?

Comment: Just add the other files into `src/main/resources` and they will be packaged automatically...

Answer (score 0):

See if the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) can help in your case.

You can associate it to the package phase, [as in this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46338862/6309). It will fail the maven process if the script returns a non-zero status.