# In Maven can we define scripts like in npm?

Tags: java, maven

In npm we can define scripts such as:

```
"start": "npm-run-all --parallet test lint ..."
```

and run it using the short command `npm start`.

Can we do the same using a Maven project?

The idea is from using npm and Node.js for a while. Current I use maven profile to config all relevant configuration and use `-D profile` to run command. But sometimes I need to disable tests using `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, it's and even worse when I update project version.

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
 -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0 \
 versions:commit
```

If possible I want to shorten the command to `mvn build-nextMinor`.

Comment: I have used gradle to write tasks and then called the task by gradle taskName. Similarly, I think there's Maven Ant tasks.

Comment: Try this-http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: exec-maven-plugin is for running java class without running java project not for define script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to execute shell commands from Maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)

Comment: Can you give an of working example, please? I just want to run maven command not java class nor shell script.

Comment: Please show the use case why you need such thing?

Answer (score 1):

No, I doubt that this is possible.

Usually, you define all relevant configuration for the plugins in the POM, then just call something like `mvn clean install`.

If you need different configurations, you can use profiles in your POM and activate them through the command line.

Comment: Yes, this's what I am using, but some time I still need to run long command such as skip test, update project version... another solution is using IDE. but all of these not as well as NPM scripts. thanks

Comment: You can also define shell commands for your common use cases.