# Run a shell script after gatling simultion

Tags: shell, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a situation where I need to execute certain commands once my Gatling simulation class is run. I was thinking to execute certain commands through shell script? How do I execute a shell script after simulation in run and the HTML file is generated? If I try to do println statement as a last statement in simulation class it doesn't even execute.

How to get a notification once the simulation is completed?

Comment: I think you would need to look at what's offered by whatever runner you're using - eg: Maven or SBT.

Comment: I am using maven runner to run gatling?

Comment: Have you considered using a [Maven task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493919/5363011) for that?