# Maven run Angular tests during build

Tags: angular, spring, maven, testing

I have a Maven based project with Spring in the backend and Angular 8 in the frontend, I would like to run the Angular unit tests automatically during the build.

I have read that usually PhantomJS was used, but it is not maintained anymore, so I would like to see a complete, even though basic, example of an application that is able to run Angular tests during the build.

I have also read that there is headless chrome available, but it is not clear to me how to wire things to make the tests run.

Does anyone can provide me with an example, please?

Comment: What version of Angular? What soft of tests (unit tests or integration tests)? Chrome headless is the way to go for both tests.

Comment: @SanderSluis info added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended to do:

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>karma</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>test</argument>
                                <argument>--</argument>
                                <argument>--watch=false</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

To run angular unit test you should run:

```
ng test
```

It will automatically download tools you need (including chrome headless). More information can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/testing.

If you must run this from maven, you can use the

```
exec-maven-plugin
```

See for example: [I want to execute shell commands from Maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)

But you are better of separating the front-end and back-end build and consider them individual artifacts.

Comment: If I run "ng test", it will wait to open a browser session. I am looking for a complete example, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: You should first get your tests to run stand alone, without maven. If 'ng test' is waiting for a browser session, you most likely have a configuration problem. Check ' karma.conf.js'.