# How to build a solaris package using maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, solaris, packaging

I have a maven project and pom.xml has nothing mentioned about packaging, so default product is jar. I want to build a solaris package for this project, how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by Solaris package?

Comment: Pkg file i suppose

Comment: No there is not any support to create a native package for a particular platform.

Comment: @khmarbaise [It most certainly is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml).  Just run the proper OS commands to create the package.  It's probably not that hard to create the proper dependencies.

Comment: when iam trying to deploy maven project, it gives me this error:
Cannot run program "pkgmk" (in directory "\"): CreateProcess error=2, The sys
tem cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

The plugin used for solaris package is unix-maven-plugin, should mention sysvpkg in packaging and run the create package statement.