# Run a script after JSweet transpilation

Tags: java, maven, transpiler, jsweet

I'm trying to build a TypeScript project with JSweet. After the transpilation, I want to run a script in any language to move some files around; specifically files that are already in TypeScript that don't need transpilation. I wrote a Groovy script that does just that but I can't make it run after the `generate-sources` instructions for JSweet.

Here's my `pom.xml` file: https://pastebin.com/932r9cWw

I am far from a Maven expert. I think the script shows that I'm trying to run the script `scripts/addJsScripts.groovy` after the transpilation, but I'm clearly doing something very wrong. The goals available to Maven Invoker plugin don't match the goals of the JSweet transpiler at all.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this, but this is more a Maven issue than a JSweet one.

I suggest you use the exec-maven-plugin, as explained here: [I want to execute shell commands from Maven's pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml)