# Using a jib for maven but non-Java application

Tags: java, docker, maven, pom.xml, jib

I am in the process of creating a project and use Jib to create containers and push them to ECR. It is a multi-module maven project which has 3 sub-modules, 2 of them are standard java spring-boot project which is woking fine with Jib and the other one is an npm project which build using mvn. Here is the pom for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>my-search-frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.11.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my search frontend</name>
    <description>my search frontend</description>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-search</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.regalo.my</groupId>
        <version>1.11.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <finalName>my-search-frontend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>node_modules</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>build</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-install</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-run-build</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipDocker>${skip.docker}</skipDocker>
                    <imageTags>
                        <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                        <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                    </imageTags>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/build</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/build</directory>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/build</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>index.html</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <to>
                        <image>${docker.repository.host}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
                    </to>
                    <!-- <skip>${skip.docker}</skip> -->
                    <extraDirectories>
                        <paths>
                            <path>
                                <from>${project.basedir}</from>
                                <into>/build</into>
                            </path>
                        </paths>
                    </extraDirectories>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Spotify one is the way previously we did it and now we are moving to Jib. But I am getting sollowing issue for this app build,

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.7.1:build (default-cli) on project my-search-frontend: Obtaining project build output files failed; make sure you have compiled your project before trying to build the image. 
(Did you accidentally run "mvn clean jib:build" instead of "mvn clean compile jib:build"?): /home/cyrex/Documents/Sourcecode/my-search/my-search-frontend/target/classes -> [Help 1]
```

Project structure of app

[image]

Help on this would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jib Maven and Gradle plugins are for Java apps, and the error message is complaining that there are no compiled `.class` files in your NPM module. However, technically, you may be able to make Jib build an NPM image with some tricks (for example, put a dummy `DummyClass.java` under `src/main/java` to bypass the error, override `<container><entrypoint>` to not execute `java`, use [`<extraDirectories>` to put arbitrary files](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image), set `<from><image>` to use a non-JRE base image, etc.). You may also need to remove files using the [Jib Layer-Filter extension](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-layer-filter-extension-maven). However, since Jib is really tailored to Java apps, I cannot really recommend it.

Just FYI, Jib is highly customizable and extensible with the [Jib Extension Framework](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions), so theoretically you could write an NPM Jib extension to cover this highly specialized workflow (and share it with the Jib community).

Also for non-Java apps and non-Maven workflows, we have other Jib solutions: [Jib Core](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-core) (the Java library) and [Jib CLI](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-cli). Jib CLI may work in this case, although it's a not a Maven plugin. (I don't know if it's a good idea, but FYI, there seems a few ways to [run an arbitrary command in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491937/i-want-to-execute-shell-commands-from-mavens-pom-xml).)

---

Related, this [article](https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/jib-docker-layer-file-filtering.html) shows an example that uses the Jib Layer-Filter extension to enable use cases not supported by Jib.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it's informative.

Answer (score 3):

To offer an alternative if anyone is still looking going forward (this was first hit for my google search):

you can set the jib plugin to use the packaged .jar file, which is auto generated if you use `mvn package` and pretty small if no code exists (~2kb)

Also make sure that your project doesn't have a parent or dependencies, otherwise jib will copy the libraries into the image.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v16.9.1</nodeVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <containerizingMode>packaged</containerizingMode>
                <extraDirectories>
                    <paths>
                        <path>
                            <from>build</from>
                            <into>/var/www/html</into>
                        </path>
                    </paths>
                </extraDirectories>
                <container>
                    <entrypoint>INHERIT</entrypoint>
                </container>
                <from>
                    <image>nginx</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>THE IMAGE NAME:${project.version}</image>
                </to>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

to create it: `mvn clean package jib:dockerBuild`

use [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to check if unnecessary files were added

Answer (score 0):

JIB is only for java projects. It handles installing a Java Runtime and dependencies in optimized layers. But it cannot create NPM docker images.

So you can only enable the jib-maven-plugin maven plugin for java modules.

For NPM, you should stick to the spotify docker-maven-plugin or something similar.
Or give [fabric8](https://maven.fabric8.io/) a try.